# replacing values in df based on condition with np.select and np.where

Tags: pandas, replace, np

I have a list of data_terms, and I'd like to loop through the col of df to replace all instances matching any item in data_terms with the word "database". I've tried with np.select:

```
discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"] = np.select(
    [discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].isin(data_terms)],
    ["database"],
    default=discrete_distributed_bar.profile_standardized,
)
```

and, with np.where:

```
for index, row in discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].items():
    np.where(
        discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].isin(data_terms),
        "database",
        row,
    )
```

but the replacement is not actually happening. What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you ad some data sample? There are no traing whitespaces? If test `print (discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].isin(data_terms))` it return correct `True` for match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here seems solution should be simplify:

```
discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"] = discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].replace(data_terms, 'database')
```

But I think there is some problem with data (e.g. whitespaces), test it by:

```
print (discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].isin(data_terms))
```

Then is possible use:

```
discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"] = discrete_distributed_bar["profile_standardized"].str.strip().replace(data_terms, 'database')
```

Comment: There must have been something else going on because it suddenly worked after many failed attempts? Thank you so much for your help! @jezrael